# Why are signed negative numbers (decimal) Converted into unsigned in Linq/Lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, decimal, code-first

I have a table called Transactions with data as such:

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[DateTime]
  ,[AccountID]
  ,[Type]
  ,[Amount]
FROM [TestModelDb].[dbo].[Transactions]
```

Outputs:

```
ID  DateTime    AccountID   Type    Amount
1   2015-03-17  1           0       10.00
2   2015-03-17  3           0       20.00
3   2015-03-17  1           0       100.00
4   2015-03-18  1           1       -10.00
5   2015-03-18  3           1       -5.00
```

I am using Code-First. When I make a simple query as the following all decimal numbers in the amount column are unsigned:

```
IEnumerable<decimal> test = Transactions.Select(t => t.Amount);
foreach (decimal amount in test)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Amount: " + amount);
}
```

Displays as in the output box:

```
Amount: 10.00
Amount: 100.00
Amount: 10.00
Amount: 20.00
Amount: 5.00
```

Why is linq or lambda query dropping the sign?

**Update #1**

The Transaction Class:

```
public partial class Transaction : EntityBase
{
    public Transaction()
    {
        DateTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the date time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The date time.</value>
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the account identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The account identifier.</value>
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Class Transaction.
    /// </summary>
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the account.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The account.</value>
    [ForeignKey("AccountID")]
    public Account Account { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The type.</value>
    [Required]
    public TransactionType Type { get; set; }

    private decimal _amount;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the amount.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The amount.</value>
    public decimal Amount
    {
        get { return _amount; }
        set
        {
            decimal temp;
            if (Type == TransactionType.Withdrawal)
                temp = value*-1;
            else temp = value;
            _amount = temp;
        } 
    }
}
```

My DbContext:

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext()
        : base("name=TestContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `Debug.WriteLine("Amount: {0}", amount);`.

Comment: Thank you for commenting @ErikE, Negative signs are still missing.

Comment: I don't understand how you are doing your query.  That code is not valid Entity Framework code.. you would need to have a DbContext to work from.  How is your Transactions class defined?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, I updated my question to show my Class and DbContext. I don't understand what you mean by "That code is not valid Entity Framework code"

Comment: He meant that you were technically doing LINQ over your transactions class, not EF.  Should still work in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework uses the setter on each property when it hydrates the object from the database call. In other words, as it builds the object it is setting the `Amount` to -10, but since it's a Withdrawal, this code (as Robert pointed out) is flipping the value back to positive:

```
if (Type == TransactionType.Withdrawal)
            temp = value*-1;
```

Try changing it to:

```
if (Type == TransactionType.Withdrawal && value > 0)
            temp = value*-1;
```

Also, as Robert commented, it's very dangers that `var t = new Transaction(); t.TransactionType=Withdrawl; t.Amount=50;` and `var t = new Transaction(); t.Amount=50;t.TransactionType=Withdrawl;` give different results.

You should probably make the `Transaction` type immutable, or at least require the type in the constructor. If you do that, rembmer that EF needs a parameterless constructor. Fortunately, it finds it through Reflection, so you can make that constructor private.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your transaction type is marked as a withdrawl so your code is flipping the number from negative to positive here:

```
if (Type == TransactionType.Withdrawal)
                temp = value*-1;
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that in your set.  At the very least, you should make a public gettable/settable property for the amount backing so it can be properly serialized, and mark your "Amount" property as not serializable, because it can't be round tripped.  Doing something as simple as: `Transaction.Amount=Transaction.Amount` will cause bugs because when it is a withdrawl, it just flipped the sign on you.

Comment: Also, `var t = new Transaction(); t.TransactionType=Withdrawl; t.Amount=50;` and `var t = new Transaction();  t.Amount=50;t.TransactionType=Withdrawl;` gives two different results, which is not very intuitive at all.  I'd say very dangerous.